Peeling Effect: geometry nodes
How to make a Peeling Effect on geometry nodes for any geometry without using paint tools?
In fact, I would like to make a geometry node like the image below, with cracks and peeling (curled in and out) in the paint on an object like a sphere or cylinder.

thanks

I'm out of mana, but I have some ideas - maybe a simulation zone, displace position based on perlin noise on face corners - capture the displaced position as an attribute, use "set position" to move verts to that attribute, check if the corners are close enough to calculated position - if not, split them?

Markus von Broady
Do you have the file or image about this geometry nodes? Thank you for your help

I have nothing, just ideas.

I have a GN setup that works. I was fiddling around and came back to post it and the question was closed. @quellenform

@Jakemoyo Sorry, I was probably too quick. Question is reopened again.

@Jakemoyo  : can you post? thanks

While I do agree with others that you might get better or easier results with texture/material based options, it IS possible to do this with GN alone. If you were to maybe use a blend of both, find some "peeling paint" heightmaps from Textures.com or something and use that as the basis for some of the textures in my node setup it might be the best of both worlds. I think experimentation will be the key to getting the best outcome.


The full modifier stack also has a SubdivisionMod before the GN tree, to add sufficient geometry, followed by a smooth modifier to even out some of the rougher edges of the holes.



thanks for the file. I have a question: how should I apply the resource to my objects? I'm not getting satisfactory results. thank you again

Another question: is there a way to apply the effect only to a small part of the mesh?

@bilo I added a bit about the other parts of the modifier stack outside of the GN tree, I think that should help you get the better results. If you want to apply it to only part of the mesh then I would create a vertex group, then get that value with a Named Attribute node and Multiply or Subtract it from the masks that go into the DeleteGeometry nodes and the Set Position node that displaces the mesh.

difficult in? Do you have a geometry nodes graph that makes the effect only apply to part of the mesh? thanks @Jakemoyo

in fact I don't have good results here. I can't apply the effect and I can't apply it to part of the mesh. Do you have a tutorial? thanks @Jakemoyo

Have you examined my file and tried to find what you're doing differently from the example mesh? It's relatively straightforward. I might have set up the default settings on all of the parameters in the GN tree perfectly. So if you added it fresh to another object it might have weird settings. Check those.

Do you know if it is possible to make the paint chips pop out more and curl up? like the first image I posted? thanks @Jakemoyo

It's not very simple to do. You're talking about vector displacement, which is outside of the scope of this question IMO. Like I and others have said, I don't think this is necessarily the best option for achieving this effect.
